# Trying to change kde setting something changed the font/font rendering and I can't go back

Tags: kubuntu, kde, fonts, plasma

I was going through [list](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1889034) (the first post)...

I changed some of the settings and some other things in the system menu, but somewhere for some reason, the font of most applications changed, and now they seem thinner and don't seem to render correctly:

[image]

I went through what I think was all the options I changed and can't seem to bring back the correct/better rendering.

I didn't change anything in the font management.

In the `application appearance > style > Fine tuning` I now have it set to high resolution high cpu, but it doesn't help.

In the `dektop effects > All effects` menu, there doesn't seem to be anything related.

`Workspace appearance` is untouched.

I'm not sure what could it be.

Answer (score 0):

In Application Appearance > Fonts, is `Use anti-aliasing` set to `System Settings`? If so, try changing it to enabled. You might also want to tweak the settings under Configure: RGB sub-pixel rendering with Slight hinting work well for me but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=326971

scroll down, it has an answer -- you have to delete `/home/(your_name)/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`.